# Can an object be used in inline javascript in an Underscore template?

Tags: underscore.js

I am looping an array in an underscore template and what to add onclick for each of the elements. Can I somehow pass the object directly to a function in the underscore template?

e.g. here I'm trying to pass the client element to the editClient() function

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <% _.each(clients, function(client) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="<% editClient(client); %> return false;"><%= client.name %></a></td>
        <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My guess is that underscore just parses everything to a string and renders the result, meaning I would need to instead pass a id to the editClient function and fetch the client using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is just rendering to html and not actually directly binding the onclick event the id should be passed instead.

e.g.

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="editClient(<%= client.id %>); return false;"><%= client.Name %></a></td>
```